# putExtra: проверка ключа

Tags: android, activity, передача-данных, проверка

Первое Activity передаёт данные через `putExtra`:

```
public class FirstClass extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent secondClass = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondClass.class);
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter1)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    secondClass.putExtra("Key1", "Text1");
                    startActivity(secondClass);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    secondClass.putExtra("Key2", "Text2");
                    startActivity(secondClass);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Второе Activity данные принимает:

```
public class SecondClass extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView;
    String name = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

Как через `if-else` (или иные способы) проверить, какой именно ключ был передан из первого Actuvity во второе, чтобы в дальнейшем выполнять соответствующие действия?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы список методов класса Intent смотреть не пробовали? Там есть один с говорящим названием [hasExtra](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Ещё, вроде, есть что-то типа `keySet()` со всеми ключами.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent().getExtras().keySet()` вернет сет из всех ключей